# Hole Alignment Probability

Tags: probability

There are $3$ identical square screens with a $3$ by $3$ square grid on each of them. In each of these screens there's exactly $1$ hole in one of the $9$ squares of each screen; its placement is random.
The screens are arranged in a sequence like this |||

1. What is the probability that there's an alignment of the $3$ holes?
2. What is the probability that there's no such alignment? Note that we have to consider exactly $2$ hole alignments for this.

My attempt:

1. The probability that for any hole in the first screen, the other $2$ holes are aligned = $\frac{1}{9} \times \frac{1}{9} = \frac{1}{81}$.
2. The probability that for any hole in the first screen, the other holes are not aligned:

Scenario 1: The first hole is aligned with the second hole but the third hole is not aligned. Probability = $\frac{1}{9} \times \frac{8}{9} = \frac{8}{81}$

Scenario 2: The first hole is not aligned with the second hole but the third hole is aligned with the second hole. Probability = $\frac{8}{9} \times \frac{1}{9} = \frac{8}{81}$

Scenario 3: The first and third wholes are aligned, but the second hole is not. Probabiity = $\frac{1}{9} \times \frac{8}{9} = \frac{8}{81}$

Scenario 4: None of the wholes are aligned = $\frac{8}{9} \times \frac{7}{9} = \frac{56}{81}$

The probability that we don't have an alignment of the holes = $\frac{8}{81} + \frac{8}{81} + \frac{8}{81}+ \frac{56}{81} = \frac{80}{81}$

Correct/no? Gracias.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, "there's no such alignment" maybe mean only the Scenario 4 you considered, but I am not sure either.

Comment: Otherwise, you only need to do $1 - \frac{1}{81} = \frac{80}{81}$ for Q2